# Authenticating RPC Server with NTLM

Tags: c#, service, rpc

I am currently trying to improve an RPC Server I'm responsible for, both server and client run on the same machine locally, however I would like to restrict the server so that it only allows administrator (including built in /LocalSystem account) to connect to the rpc server through a named pipe.

First of all I am using the following library as a wrapper for the RPCserverApi/RPCClientApi:
https://github.com/csharptest/CSharpTest.Net.RpcLibrary

I create the Server like so:

```
server = new RpcServerApi(IId, MaxCalls, ushort.MaxValue, true);
server.AddProtocol(RpcProtseq.ncacn_np, Id, MaxCalls);
// Set authentication
server.AddAuthentication(RpcAuthentication.RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT);
```

However when I check the named pipes security it still shows like it's not restricted at all, and my client can still connect even though I have yet to change that to specify authentication.

In addition I can check the access to that named pipe and I get:

```
\\.\pipe\myNamedPipe
  RW Everyone
  RW NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So for anyone else that ran into this problem There's a few things I needed to do which was not exposed in the library I was using.  So instead I created my own wrapper.

When Registering the Rpc Interface with RpcServerRegisterIf2() I had to pass through the flag:
RPC_IF_ALLOW_SECURE_ONLY

Then In addition when setting up the protocols for the RpcServer: RpcServerUseProtseqEp() I also had to pass through an SDDL, to describe the restrictions on the end point.  You can find a description of SDDL's here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptor-definition-language

To do this I created an Ace String, then used ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor() to create the correct object.  This then locked down the end point like:

```
\\.\pipe\myNamedPipe 
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
```

But also it enforced on the server that only authenticated accounts could reach it

My issue originally reported was full of misunderstandings about RPC Servers and Named pipes, I thoroughly recommend reading and understanding the following articles, as they were very helpful to me.

https://csandker.io/2021/01/10/Offensive-Windows-IPC-1-NamedPipes.html
https://csandker.io/2021/02/21/Offensive-Windows-IPC-2-RPC.html